# Use service account to login to cloud console GUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, report, service-accounts, billing, google-cloud-iam

I am in the process of setting up a single board computer which displays GCP billing info graphs on a large screen. Rather than using my own owner credentials to show the graphs on the pi (which is secured already), i would like to use a service account to login to GCP backend and delegate only billing viewer role to that account. I use service accounts regularly for command line programs etc, but I can't figure out a way to actually login to the GUI portion of gcp console with a service key. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You cannot log in to the Google Cloud Console (GUI) using a service account.

The supported methods are:

1. OAuth 2.0 User Credentials - the method you are currently using.
2. SSO - Single Sign-On.

Comment: Okay; I got around this by creating a new email account from work and added permissions to this as billing viewer only.